# How can I set my bluetooth visibility on all the time with lollipop?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, bluetooth, 5.1-lollipop

I use my phone as a beacon. When I show up places, other bits of hardware notice my bluetooth presence and do things.
As of lollipop apparently this doesn't work anymore because there is no way to have bluetooth visibility on all the time.

Is there a  way I can force bluetooth visibility on all the time?

I'd really rather avoid writing yet another app, especially if somebody already has one, but I have had no luck finding anything on the play store.

Comment: App recommendations are off topic so edited your question

Comment: [Blue tooth auto connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.myklos.btautoconnect) description seems to allow that. I downloaded app today for something else but didn't try fully

Comment: doesn't seem to have any settings for visibility, just what to do when bluetooth is turned on and off.

Answer (score 0):

This app sorta does what I want, but it doesn't start on boot, which means I've have to push some buttons which defeats the purpose. I'm trying to automate the process.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tcompany.bluetoothdiscovery&hl=en

So the answer will be, I write the app myself.
Thanks for the help.